# permission denied при createNewFile на SD карту api 23

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте.

```
package com.elf_m.android.testsdcard;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {
    Button mButton;
    private View mLayout;

    private static final int PERMISSION_STORAGE = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_layout);


        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SaveFile();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                           int[] grantResults) {
        // BEGIN_INCLUDE(onRequestPermissionsResult)
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_STORAGE) {
            // Request for camera permission.
            if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission has been granted. Start camera preview Activity.
                Toast.makeText(this, "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Starting SaveFile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                SaveFileToSD();
            } else {
                // Permission request was denied.
                Toast.makeText(this, "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission request was denied.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        // END_INCLUDE(onRequestPermissionsResult)
    }

    private void SaveFile() {
        // BEGIN_INCLUDE(startCamera)
        // Check if the Camera permission has been granted
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission is already available, start camera preview
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is available.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            SaveFileToSD();
        } else {
            // Permission is missing and must be requested.
            requestWRITEEXTERNALPermission();
        }
        // END_INCLUDE(startCamera)
    }

    private void requestWRITEEXTERNALPermission() {
        // Permission has not been granted and must be requested.
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            // Provide an additional rationale to the user if the permission was not granted
            // and the user would benefit from additional context for the use of the permission.
            // Display a SnackBar with a button to request the missing permission.
            Snackbar.make(mLayout, "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE access is required to display the camera preview.",
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // Request the permission
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            PERMISSION_STORAGE);
                }
            }).show();

        } else {
            Snackbar.make(mLayout,
                    "Permission is not available. Requesting WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.",
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Request the permission. The result will be received in onRequestPermissionResult().
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    PERMISSION_STORAGE);
        }
    }

    public void SaveFileToSD() {
        try
        {
            File fhandle = new File(getSDcardPath().toString() + "/myfolder111/test.txt");

            //Если нет директорий в пути, то они будут созданы:
            if (!fhandle.exists())
                if(!fhandle.mkdirs())
                    Log.d("test", "Ошибка создания папки!");

            //Если файл существует, то он будет перезаписан:
            if(!fhandle.createNewFile())
                Log.d("test", "Ошибка создания документа");

            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(fhandle);
            OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            myOutWriter.write("TEST");
            myOutWriter.close();
            fOut.close();

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


    private String getSDcardPath()
    {
        String exts =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        String sdCardPath = null;
        try
        {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(new File("/proc/mounts"));
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line;
            while((line = br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                if(line.contains("secure") || line.contains("asec"))
                    continue;
                if(line.contains("fat"))
                {
                    String[] pars = line.split("\\s");
                    if(pars.length<2)
                        continue;
                    if(pars[1].equals(exts))
                        continue;
                    sdCardPath =pars[1];
                    break;
                }
            }
            fr.close();
            br.close();
            return sdCardPath;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        return sdCardPath;
    }

}
```

Comment: Второй день уже бьюсь, может нужно дополнительные разрешения для записи на SD карту?

Comment: А в манифесте прописали   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> ?

Comment: Да, конечно прописал, и получаю его дополнительно. Подключение по USB у планшета нет.

Comment: Посмотри все же в офф документацию https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#java когда я делал всё как тут написано, то проблем не имел.

Comment: Переписал, все сделал по документации. Все тоже самое, при записи файла : permission denied . Такое ощущение, что ещё что-то нужно для записи на SD карту

Comment: Вот такое в Лог валиться при попытке создания папки:01-22 00:17:58.290 11858-11858/com.elf_m.android.testsdcard W/roid.testsdcard: type=1400 audit(0.0:94): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/mnt/media_rw" dev="tmpfs" ino=1487 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:mnt_media_rw_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0

Comment: Попробовал на другом уст-ве, та же ошибка. Путь до карты памяти получает нормально, но при создании папки, папка не создается

Comment: Завтра (точнее уже сегодня по мск) днём повожусь с этим кодом в Android Studio, так легче будет понять, что и куда.

Comment: выложил целиком код для удобства

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрел код.

```
 if (pars[1].equals(exts))
       continue;

                sdCardPath = pars[1];
                Log.d("SaveFileToSD", "pars " + pars[1]);
                Log.d("SaveFileToSD", "pars " + pars[0]);

                break;
```

В месте, что я привел выше `sdCardPath = pars[1];` не вызывается потому что, не выполняется его условие и возвращается null. Так же насчет proc/mounts, папки mounts нет не на одном моем девайсе, плюс вы пытаетесь записать файлы в корневой каталог (получаем permission denied, для этого нужен root) `Ошибка создания папки! null/myfolder111/test.txt` при этом как я и сказал getSDcardPath ничего не возвращает. Не знаю насколько я помог, но код как и обещал посмотрел.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! На моих уст-вах, везде путь возвращался. Вопрос то остался, как записать файлы на SD карту, если API больше KitKat. Посмотрел через ADB, действительно на все папки SD карты права root. При том я специально папку создаю на компе, подключая к нему SD карту

Comment: Может есть у кого готовый кусок кода, для записи файлов на SD карту?
 HELP!!! Мне блин базу SQLite нужно туда перенести и оттуда с ней работать и никак уже третий день